# Are loggers considered global mutable state

Tags: oop, logging, global-variables

First let me say that by "logger" I mean any class of object that is responsible for reporting diagnostic or progress information to the user or the programmer.  By this definition a "logger" would include feedback on the GUI such as a progress bar.

We have been repeatedly told to avoid global state, and global mutable state **(GMS)** especially.  Since loggers are inherently mutable, I recently tried to make my loggers "not global".  I tried various strategies (like injecting the reference to the logger via the constructor).  I finally realized that all those methods are just putting lipstick on a pig.

A logger must be accessible by all classes (or at least most of them) if it is going to be useful.   Thus it is global.   And it must be mutable; what good is a logger whose document can't be appended?  Or a progress bar whose value can't change?   It doesn't matter if you make the logger a Singleton, or if use dependency injection, or create a static method to hold the reference.  No matter how you slice it, a logger is going to be GMS.

It seems the best I can do is create a very small container class, that (statically) creates  the logger, and makes a reference to that logger available (globally) through static methods.

So at long last to my question.
Is a logger really what we are worried about when we talk about GMS?   You write to it, but you (almost) never read from it.  Is a logger really GMS at all?

A global logger must be created statically, at least in Java, so it can be accessed through static methods.    That makes it a pain to test with.   But what can we do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Technically the loggers you describe are GMS, but no, they're not what we're worried about when we talk about GMS. The reason is that they're in essence *write-only*, so the state doesn't affect anything back in the rest of the program. And sure, you have to make sure they actually are write-only, as much as reasonably possible (i.e. it's usually OK to not worry about your file logger filling up the filesystem; it wouldn't be OK to ask it how many lines it's logged so far).

As to your testing question: The logger itself can of course be an ordinary class that gets tested on its own. Other code's interactions with the unique global instance of the logger are a pain to test, so it's often preferable to just make those bits of code absolutely minimal and straightforward, and leave them untested.

If you really want to test those too, a pragmatic solution is to give that container class a `setInstance` as well as a `getInstance`. It's probably best in this case to make the default class-instantiated logger in effect a no-op one, and let the main application initialize the real production logger via `setInstance`.

**Theory waffle:** "Global" literally just means it can be accessed from everywhere (global as in access). It usually also implies that there's only one of it (global as in a lowercase-s singleton). The problems that usually arise from these two are:

1. it's not obvious from call sites when your code depends on a global
2. if mutable, it allows hidden interactions between any two parts of the system at all
3. it's hard to use an alternative instance - usually a testing concern, but sometimes also a headache with production code.

*Generally*, wrapping something in a (global!) class doesn't make it any less global - it's still accessible by anyone, and by default there's still only one of it.  The only bit of advantage is that, in Java specifically, it makes the code look more disciplined and communicates that you've thought about the issue.

That global-as-in-singleton thing can be worked around, e.g. with something similar to a Factory pattern, but for objects that may be pre-generated, and this would fix the alternative-instance problem.

The global-as-in-access problems are AFAICT unsolvable, but they can be mitigated via finer-grained control over who gets access (making the object *less-than-entirely global*), by passing the instance around into every possible constructor (or method call), either manually or via some dependency-injection library. The manual solution of course makes for boilerplatey code; the DI libs have a learning curve and still non-zero boilerplate compared to plain globals.

*Specifically* in the case of loggers as you describe them, #1 is taken as an acceptable assumption that literally every piece of code might log something; #2 is solved by the logger guaranteeing that, though mutable, it's unable to let other pieces of code covertly or accidentally affect each other; and #3 can be solved for example by that `setInstance` thing, a very "lite" variant of the Factory-oid solution.

Comment: Thank you for this well considered response.  I particularly liked the bit at the end where you say that #2 is solved by preventing objects from interacting.  That seems to be real core of the GMS problem, even when it comes to making reliable unit tests.   It was much better than my "write only" excuse.  You said it was probably best to allow the main application to initialize the real production logger via a setInstance type function.  Why do you suggest that?

Comment: Thinking of the logger class(es) as a library that's used by the main app (presumably reused by multiple main apps) I'd say the configuration of how we want things logged is better decided by the app than the library.

Say we want it in a file in `/var/tmp/my_app_name/log` - that name isn't something that would reasonably be hardcoded in a library. But if this is a once-off logger written only for a practice/toy project, there isn't a pragmatic difference - it becomes just a tradeoff between discipline/hygiene for practice's sake and finishing the program sooner and with less code.

Comment: That makes good sense!  I was only thinking of it as a "once off".  However, even as a once off, it might be re-used.  And even if it is not re-used, interacting with it as if it were a (reusable) library is likely make the code in the main class easier to understand. I found a few practical reasons too.  The location of the log "file" was sometimes part of the UI.  I hated having to create that statically!   Also some of its configuration would come from a config file which took I/O to read.